# Are there any command line tools to generate windows icons?

Tags: command-line, image, icons

I am working on a project that requires a number of icons generated from a set of source images.  I have a script that generates all the required images with judicious use of [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php), although I have not found a suitable tool to package the images as icons.

I have a set of png files (from dimensions of 16x16 up to 256x256, and in a range of bit depths) and I would like to generate some nice vista icons in the build script.  The closest tool I have found to what I need is [png2ico](http://winterdrache.de/freeware/png2ico/), although this fails to cope with the large Vista icons, and does not support proper transparency in the icons it produces.

Before I invest time in writing such a tool, does anyone know of anything that will do the job?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since GConvert won't work for you, perhaps this will be more useful:

#### [Resource Tuner Console](http://www.heaventools.com/command-line_resource_editor.htm)

> Resource Tuner Console is an efficient and highly customizable script driven
> resource editor with a command-line interface that supports the creation and
> editing of resources in 32- and 64-bit Windows EXE or DLL files.

See specifically the batch manipulation of icons page for some additional info:

- http://www.heaventools.com/rtconsole-replace-icons.htm

Unrelated, but also may be useful:
[How to compile Windows Vista icons](http://www.rw-designer.com/compile-vista-icon)

Comment: That seems to do exactly what I need; although I am loathe to spend $100 on an app which I only need a tiny amount of functionality in.  I guess I just need to work out whether quickly hacking together a tool is less than $100 worth of effort (I suspect not).

Answer (score 1):

> Before I invest time in writing such a
>   tool, does anyone know of anything
>   that will do the job?

The **png2ico** web page that you provided has a link to the source code for the tool.

Why not start by just trying to fix the tool you have?

Comment: Since the code is quite low level I would have to work out the file format  and it would require versions for several colour depths, I would probably be able to knock out some quick and dirty WinAPI code to do it far quicker.  That, and the fact that my C is not up to scratch.

Answer (score 1):

In case anyone needs this: icoutils contains icotool which may help: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man1/icotool.1.html

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this will fit the bill, but the description says it supports "batch" operations so you should be able to automate the process.

#### [GConvert](http://www.gdgsoft.com/gconvert/)

> GConvert is a full-featured icon toolkit that lets you extract, create, edit,
> manage, compile and convert icons. It reads any icon resource file (EXE, DLL,
> ICL, OCX, NIL, CPL, SCR, RSRC, ICNS...) and then allows you to save extracted
> icons in other image formats (ICO, BMP, PNG, GIF, Photoshop PSD, JPG and more

The page also specifically mentions that it fully supports Vista icons. Caveat is that there's a free trial but the license is $25.00

Comment: I've just had a look at that tool.  The "batch mode" seems to only be activatable through the GUI and hence not what I am looking for.  Otherwise it seems it would do the job.